# How can I identify if a certain row is the last by using an ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry to confuse you about my title. I am building an auction system and I am having a difficulty in getting the user's winning item.

Example I have a table like this:

[image]

the columns are:
id, product_id, user_id, status, is_winner, info, bidding_price, bidding_date

here's my sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7097d/1

I want to get every user's item that they already win. So I need to identify if they are the last who bid in that item.
I need to filter it using a user_id.

If I do a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(product_id) AS product_id FROM auction_product_bidding
WHERE user_id = 3;
```

it will get only the product_id that is 12 and the product_id of 9 did not get. Product ID 9 is also that last bid of the user_id 3.

Can you help me? I hope you got my point. Thanks. Sorry if my question a little bit confusing.

Comment: use an order by blah desc limit 1 ?

Comment: If I did that I can only get 1 value. I need to get the product ID `if the user is the last who bid` in that item.

Comment: have the product id in the where clause? I am not sure what you are after.

Comment: Sorry I modified the picture so that you can see other example if it has other users. In the picture you can see there are other user ID. Example I am user ID 3 and I need to get the product ID that I am the last who bid in that item. So in my image these product IDs are 9, 11 and 12. And the product ID 10 is not because the last who bid is user ID 2. I hope you can get my point, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, seems 11 is also what you want, try this query:

```
SELECT apd.product_id
FROM auction_product_bidding apd
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(bidding_date) AS bidding_date, product_id
    FROM auction_product_bidding
    GROUP BY product_id
) t
ON apd.product_id = t.product_id
AND apd.bidding_date = t.bidding_date
WHERE apd.user_id = 3;
```

[<kbd>Check Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7097d/10)

Comment: @Jerielle I've read that, this query gives 9,11,12, check the demo above.

Comment: Yeah thanks I am checking it now if it is correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id,product_id,user_id,status,is_winner,info,bidding_price,bidding_date,rank
from
(   SELECT apb.*, 
    greatest(@rank:=if(product_id=@prodGrp,@rank+1,1),-1) as rank,
    @prodGrp:=product_id as dummy
    FROM auction_product_bidding apb
    cross join (select @prodGrp:=-1,@rank:=0) xParams
    order by product_id,bidding_date DESC
) xDerived
where user_id=3 and rank=1;
```

That user won 9,11,12

```
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+---------------+---------------------+------+
| id | product_id | user_id | status | is_winner | info | bidding_price | bidding_date        | rank |
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+---------------+---------------------+------+
| 60 |          9 |       3 |        |         0 |      |      75000.00 | 2016-08-02 16:31:23 |    1 |
| 59 |         11 |       3 |        |         0 |      |      15000.00 | 2016-08-02 12:04:16 |    1 |
| 68 |         12 |       3 |        |         0 |      |      18000.00 | 2016-08-10 09:20:01 |    1 |
+----+------------+---------+--------+-----------+------+---------------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: I have a nose bleed right now when I read you query. It is too advance for me :) It is correct also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(select product_id,user_id,max(bidding_price) from 
(select * from auction_product_bidding order by bidding_price desc) a
group by product_id) b
where user_id=3;
```

**Answer:**

```
product_id   user_id    max(bidding_price)
9            3          75000
11           3          15000
12           3          18000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_id FROM auction_product_bidding where bidding_price= any     
(select max(bidding_price) from auction_product_bidding group by product_id) 
and user_id='3';
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You want everything that bids last in 3, is it right ?

Comment: I updated my image. Example I am user ID 3 and I need to get the product ID that I am the last who bid in that item.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to sort the table desc by date and select every distinct row by product_id and customer_id. Something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT prod_id, user_id FROM (
SELECT * FROM auction_product_bidding ORDER BY date DESC
)
```